# Install dlib error not found cublas_v2

Tags: tensorflow, dlib

Trying to install dlib with GPU support.
Use tf image

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3
```

Install cudnn

```
COPY cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.1.tgz ./
RUN tar -zxvf cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.1.tgz
RUN cp -P cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
RUN cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
RUN chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

And than install dlib

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib
RUN cd dlib && python3 setup.py install
```

I get this error

> [  1%] Building NVCC (Device) object
>   dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/dlib_generated_cuda_dlib.cu.o [ 
>   1%] Building NVCC (Device) object
>   dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/dlib_generated_cusolver_dlibapi.cu.o
>   /notebooks/dlib/dlib/cuda/cusolver_dlibapi.cu:9:23: fatal error:
>   cublas_v2.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated. CMake
>   Error at dlib_generated_cusolver_dlibapi.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
>   Error generating
>   /notebooks/dlib/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/./dlib_generated_cusolver_dlibapi.cu.o

if I don't install cudnn dlib builds successfully but with notification that it doesn't use CUDA.

Tried to google but people write to set USE_CPU_ONLY=1 (they have the error for caffe) which is not what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem. Install cublas-dev (sudo apt install cuda-cublas-dev-9-0) solved it for me.

Comment: for now name changed to libcublas-dev-...


    `cuda-cublas-10-0  - CUBLAS native runtime libraries;  cuda-cublas-dev-10-0  - CUBLAS native dev links, headers` 


but 


    `libcublas-11-0 - CUBLAS native runtime libraries;    libcublas-dev-11-0 - CUBLAS native dev links, headers`